Proteus X-Y mode graph
I am trying to plot the I-V characteristic plot of diode. However when I am dc sweeping the DC voltage source and plot the Id probe it is actually giving me Id vs V1 plot. But I want Id in the y axis and Vd in the x axis not V1.Is there any way to change the x axis variable?


Remove the resistor, sweep the DC source V1 from 0...1V and plot current Id through the diode.

You can also use a current generator .... across diode, no resistor.
